# How to set object keys as values from another object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have a type declaration of this shape

```
interface BrokerData  {
    Icon?: string;
    ID: number;
    Name?: string;
    VATNumber?: string;
}
```

And trying to create another one related to the previous one. It should be an object, whose keys are ID-s of the IBrokerData ( not the type of ID-s, but the actual values ). The first thing that came to my mind is this.

```
type AnotherData = Record<BrokerData['ID'], unknown>
```

But unfortunately, it is not a valid typescript code.

Comment: Does `type AnotherData = Record<BrokerData['ID'], BrokerData>` not work?

Comment: Typescript warns me about an unexpected token.

Comment: Check [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJQPYGtoBE5hzLIDeAUMcQJIIYgD8AXMgM5hSgDmA3BZVbmYgArgFsARtF6VkAOTiiITVuy7TKANQCCAFVljJUZWw4geZAL5kyYAJ4AHFFpAYwACzwEiAXmQAlCFooABMAHnRsT0IAbQByAViAXQAaNEwcKHxCAD5rWhA2ZGCvZmdXD0yvZF9yGQBGZhJkAWY65AtkvmI6gAYexpbkXp7U+UVmWIApDDcQWKsrIA) There is no error or warning.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems I have missed something when I got an error by typescript.